# Get the number of posts x category from date y

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a dictionary system which kinda works like urban dictionary. i want to get the number of posts of today/yesterday/random. the table structure i'm using right now is like this:

words:

```
|id|name  |lastupdate(unixstyle)
|1 |apple |today
|2 |potato|yesterday
|3 |pear  |today
|4 |php   |three days ago
```

definitions:

```
|id|wordid|date
|1 |1     |three days ago
|1 |4     |three days ago
|1 |1     |three days ago
|1 |2     |yesterday
|1 |2     |yesterday
|1 |1     |yesterday
|1 |4     |today
|1 |3     |today
|1 |1     |today
```

with this table structure i can easily get the number of definitions of today. but what i actually wanna do is to be able to get the posts of anyday i want.

the result i want kinda looks like this:

```
today's words:
apple(1 definition)
pear(3 definitions)
php(4 definitions)
```

it's my first post on stackoverflow :) i hope i clearly said what i wanna do. i'll be glad if someone could help me with this problem.

thanks in advance :)

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I found the solution after hours of research(silly me). All i had to do is use INNER JOIN to get what i want. The solution is like this:

```
SELECT words.name
FROM words
INNER JOIN definitions ON words.id = definitions.wordid
WHERE date > 1354053600
```

The date i used is an example of course. All you need to do is change it using the unixdate you want :)

Comment: what it the dataType of your dates? is it a string?

Comment: Using mysql datetime for your dates lets you do arbitrary queries. Using datetime you can do textual queries like so: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`

Comment: @lbu i use php's time() function. Martin Sommervold, i can't understand what you said. could you give more details?

Comment: Are you saying you are actually storing "yesterday" etc as the value for date?  Why is definitions.id always equal to 1 in your sample data?  Shouldn't those be unique ids?

Comment: no, i don't. i use unix style time(php's time function). oh... i forgot to change those ids while pasting them... silly me. of course they are real.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please remove the answer from your question and *post it as an actual answer*, and then mark your answer accepted.